# Retrieve object rotation from face normal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, rotation, quaternions

I would like to rotate an object to match its ground. So i cast 3 Rays (at the corners) to calculate the normal of the plane below.
Now i need to rotate the object accordingly but keep the y rotation (so in which direction it "faces") so just setting `transform.up = normal` does not work.
I thought i could just use the dot product between the transform directions to rotate it (so `xRotation = Vector3.Dot(normal, transform.forward)` for x and `zRotation = Vector3.Dot(normal, transform.right)` for z) this should be the angles between the normal vector and the right/forward vector. But as the result my object just faces the sky that way to the idea is completely wrong.
Do you know how i should proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem. Although there are different methods for doing this, I personally find it best to use the `Cross` axis. In fact, you need `Vector3.Cross` instead of `Vector3.Dot`. This code works in such a way that by multiplying the `transform.right` of the player on the Ground normal vector, Since this axis calculates the perpendicular direction, you can expect it to give a forward corresponding to the ground.

```cs
public LayerMask groundLayer; // The Layer Ground
public Vector3 offset = Vector3.up;

private void Update()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out var groundHit, 2f, groundLayer.value))
    {
        var cross = Vector3.Cross(transform.right, groundHit.normal);

        var _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cross, groundHit.normal);

        transform.position = groundHit.point + offset; // the offset is OPTIONAL, you can adjust it manuel or remove

        transform.rotation = _lookRotation;
    }   
}
```

---

### Result:

You can see the result below. Consider that you can delete the offset code and make it compatible with the ground with mechanisms such as `CharacterController` or `Rigidbody`.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks the Quaternion magic works like a charm.